# mongod command for using mongodb-community version in Macos Mojave gives error

Tags: mongodb, macos, installation, failed-installation, database-installation

I am using macos Mojave 10.14.5 on a Macbook Air 2017. I have installed mongodb-community version using terminal by running the commands,

```
brew tap mongodb/brew
brew install mongodb-community
```

after that I also made the default folder using,

```
sudo mkdir -p /data/db
```

and I changed the ownership as,

```
sudo chown -Rv dhruvbansal /data/db
```

Then I ran the command mongod in the terminal but it is not starting the mongo-daemon shell. The screenshot is attached here.

[image]

Comment: please help to solve this problem, i am in the middle of a course and unable to proceed further due to this...

Comment: Pls help with this...